# return python `time` object to front end?

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

In python, the `timedate` library contains a `datetime` (timestamp`, a`date`and a`time` class. Is there a *time-only* (not corresponding to a specific date) concept in

- javascript
- iso 8601

so, that I can return the `datetime.time` object to the front end in a standardized manner?

Comment: What is "a standardized manner"?

Comment: I meant an ISO8601 representation, which is directly deserialized by javascript. Just like you can do with timestamps

Comment: there's only Date object in js, not just standalone time https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Are you talking about a duration (8 hrs 30 mins) or a repeating interval (every day at noon)?  [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) has some techniques to parse iso8601 durations.

Comment: @James: a repeating time. regardless of day, eg "schools open at 9:00".

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.time()
datetime.time(11, 39, 33, 932976)
>>> now.time().isoformat()
'11:39:33.932976'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) to return an ISO8601 formatted string from a `datetime` object.